# Iterative Methods for Solving a PDE?

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Given the following PDE: $-\Delta u + u = 1$ in the domain $[0,1]^2$ and $u = 0$ as the boundary condition, I want to solve for the solution via an iterative method (Gauss-Seidel / Jacobi, for example).

If I let $h = 1/(n+1)$ the unknowns in the following equation are $x_{i,j}$ for $\space 1, ..., n$ that satisfy:
$$(4+h^2)x_{i,j} - x_{i-1,j} - x_{i,j-1} - x_{i+1,j} - x_{i,j+1} = h^2$$ for $i,j = 1, ... , n$

and
$$x_{0,j} = x_{n+1,j} = x_{i,0} = x_{i,n+1} = 0, \quad \text{for} \quad i,j = 1, ..., n$$

**Question:**

I believe the unknowns $x$ are a $n \times n$ matrix, which would make $A$ in $Ax = b$ a 4th order tensor, but does $A$ need to be constructed in order to implement an iterative method? If not why? If so, how would $A$ look? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer to address what $A$ can look like.
I don't know iterative methods.
Suppose we arrange the $x_{ij}$ into a column vector with
$x_{11},\ldots,x_{1n}$ as the first $n$ entries, followed by
$x_{21},\ldots,x_{2n}$ and so forth down to $x_{nn}$.
Then most rows of $A$
have $d = 4+h^2$  on the diagonal with a $-1$ to each side, and two more $-1$'s located $n$ places to left and right, as below. But this has to be modified for
points $(i,j)$ adjacent to the boundary. The $4\times 4$ case is
representative:
$$
\begin{smallmatrix}
 d &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr  
-1 & d &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr  
 0 &-1 & d &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr  
 0 & 0 &-1 & d & 0 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr  
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & d &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr  
 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & d &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr  
 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & d &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr  
 0 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & d & 0 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr  
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & d &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr  
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & d &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 \cr  
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & d &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 \cr  
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & d & 0 & 0 & 0 &-1 \cr  
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & d &-1 & 0 & 0 \cr  
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & d &-1 & 0 \cr  
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & d &-1 \cr  
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1 & d  
\end{smallmatrix}
$$
Here in rows 4,5,8,9,12,13, or more generally in matrix rows $kn,(k+1)n$,
you omit one $-1$ because you are at the end of a row of nodes
adjacent to a zero boundary value.
Also in the first $n$ and last $n$  matrix rows you omit one or two
$-1$'s because you are on the first and last row of nodes that have
zero boundary values adjacent.

That $4\times 4$ can be expressed as
$$
A = I\otimes\begin{bmatrix}d & -1 & 0 & 0 \cr
                              -1 & d & -1 & 0 \cr
                               0 & -1 & d & -1 \cr
                               0 & 0 & -1 & d\end{bmatrix}
 +\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \cr
                 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \cr
                 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \cr
                 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\otimes I.
$$

Comment: I confirmed your answer via coding the conditions and reordering along the main diagonal! The visualization was incredibly helpful

Comment: It might be useful to know that eigenvectors of $I\otimes B+C\otimes I$ are tensor products of the eigenvectors of $B$ and $C$, when $I$, $B$, and $C$ are the same size.